# Como fazer a posição de uma div que se movimenta ser salva aoutomaticamente?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, div

Desenvolvi um widget para meu projeto e agora preciso que, ao move-lo, sua posição fique salva.

Exemplo: Posição inicial do widget `80px` x `120px`, após movimento lo, posição inicial do widget `210px` x `300px`.

Espero que minha dúvida fique clara.

Comment: Entender eu acho que dá, mas em qual parte do procedimento você está com dificuldade?

Comment: Tipo a parte onde ele pega a posição que eu deixei e salva no css

Comment: @Daniel alterar o arquivo CSS vai dar muito trabalho, acredito que `localStorage` seja uma boa opção.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se entendi sua pergunta, você tem uma `div` que se desloca sobre a página e você quer que sempre a ultima posição ocupada por ela fique salva ao carregar a pagina novamente, correto ? Bom, se for isto mesmo, desenvolvi um `script` e usando o `localStorage` salvo a ultima posição, `left` e `top`, da `div`.
Não será possível implementar o código no snippet do StackOverflow por que ele não permite a utilização do `localStorage` por motivos de segurança.
 Você pode ver a implementação funcionando perfeitamente no [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/devgaspa/cp711tt3/).

Script:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var box = document.getElementById('box');
  var draggable = false;
  var bLeft = localStorage.getItem('bLeft') || '';
  var bTop = localStorage.getItem('bTop') || '';

  box.style.left = bLeft;
  box.style.top = bTop;

  box.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
    draggable = true;
  });

  window.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
    draggable = false;
  });

  window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    if(draggable) {
      box.style.left = (e.clientX - 50) + 'px';
      box.style.top = (e.clientY - 50) + 'px';

      localStorage.setItem('bLeft', box.style.left);
      localStorage.setItem('bTop', box.style.top);

    }
  });
});
```

> Veja funcionando no [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/devgaspa/cp711tt3/)

Referência: [MDN - localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/Window.localStorage)

Comment: Mano tudo certo so um probleminha, ele fica selecionado não importa oque eu faço.

Comment: Boa. Daniel: isso vai salvar a posição no computador e no browser que você estiver usando. Se quiser que persista entre computadores ou browsers diferentes, você vai precisar salvar a posicao num banco de dados, ou num arquivo no servidor.

Comment: @Daniel talvez por que o `mouseup` estivesse no `box`, alterei para o objeto `window`, teste parar ver se para.

Comment: @devgaspa alterei certinho, só que o problema é que ele acaba abrindo uma margem de uns '50 px' do cursor do mouse

Comment: @Daniel se você olhar no código, essa parte `(e.clientX - 50)`, tanto left como o top são subtraídos a metade da largura e altura do box para que o mouse fique centralizado no mesmo. Enfim, você tem que alterar o valor `50` para a metade do seu box